# Redirect adding absolute path when using {redirect="{page_url}"}

Tags: redirects

I recently upgraded to EE2 2.11.7 and I was using a redirect to automatically redirect user if on search results if there was an exact match.

This was working fine for me previously: `{if total_results == 1}{redirect="{page_url}"}{/if}`

But now getting error, `The URI you submitted is not allowed.`. And the URL is adding the absolute path on top of the domain like this: `http://example.com/http:/example.com/page/url/entry`

I can use some jQuery to fix with a trigger click, but it's kind of clunky. Any way to fix that url to properly redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using {page_uri} instead of {page_url}
The redirect tag is looking for a relative, not absolute value.